# Sum column for stock calculation

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to calculate stock in sql. I've 3 table product, purchase and sales.
product table is

```
+----+------------------+
| id | product_name     | 
+----+------------------+
| 1  | apple            | 
|----|------------------|
| 2  |banana            | 
|----|------------------|
| 3  |mango             | 
+----+------------------+
```

Now color table

```
+----+------------------+
| id |   color_name     | 
+----+------------------+
| 1  |   dark           | 
|----|------------------|
| 2  |   light          | 
+----|------------------+
```

purchase table is

```
+-------+-------------+
| id    | quantity    |color
+-------+-------------+
|   1   |   15        |dark
+-------+-------------+
|   1   |   10        |light
+-------+-------------+
|   2   |   5         |dark
+-------+-------------+
|   3   |   25        |light
+-------+-------------+
```

and sales table is

```
+-------+-------------+
| id    | quantity    |color
+-------+-------------+
|   1   |   5         |dark
+-------+-------------+
|   1   |   5         |light
+-------+-------------+
|   2   |   5         |dark
+-------+-------------+
|   3   |   5         |light
+-------+-------------+
```

Purchase and sales table have foreign key id references id of product table. Now I'm trying to calculate stock available i.e. difference of purchase and sales in below format on the basis of color too

```
+----+------------------+-------------+
| id | product_name     | quantity    |color
+----+------------------+-------------+
| 1  | apple            |    10       |dark
|----|------------------|-------------|
| 1  | apple            |    5        |light
|----|------------------|-------------|
| 2  |banana            |    0        |dark
|----|------------------|-------------|
| 3  |mango             |    20       |light
+----+------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may looking for this

```
SELECT p.id,p.Name,Purchase.purchaseQty-sales.salseQty as totalQty
FROM Product p
OUTER APPLY(
         SELECT  purchase.id, SUM(purchase.quantity) purchaseQty
         FROM purchase 
         where purchase.id= p.id
         GROUP BY purchase.id
)Purchase
OUTER APPLY(
         SELECT  sales.id, SUM(sales.quantity) salseQty
         FROM sales
         where sales.id= p.id
         GROUP BY sales.id
)sales
```

Comment: what if we have another table color what will be best query for calculating stock on the basis of color too like available quantity of apple with red color and apple with light red

Comment: I've changed the question can you check it for me

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.product_name, 
SUM(b.quantity) - SUM(c.quantity) as 'quantity'
FROM product a 
LEFT JOIN purchase b 
ON a.id=b.id 
LEFT JOIN sales c 
ON b.id = c.id group by a.id, a.product_name
```

(I didn't test anything)

Comment: what if there is no record of sales of certain product? It will be null if not provided how to solve it

Comment: There is an SQL method for that, but I can't remember (it replace null by 0)

Comment: got it : SELECT ISNULL(c.quantity, 0). The syntax depend of the type of database you are using

Comment: Are you sure your query won't multiply purchase and sales records?

Comment: It won't because of the group by

Comment: I've changed question as new problem arises please check  it for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution with outer apply.

```
drop table if exists dbo.tProduct;
drop table if exists dbo.tPurchase;
drop table if exists dbo.tSale;

create table dbo.tProduct (
    id int
    , product_name varchar(100)
);

create table dbo.tPurchase (
    id int
    , quantity int
);

create table dbo.tSale (
    id int
    , quantity int
);

insert into dbo.tProduct (id, product_name)
values (1, 'apple'), (2, 'banana'), (3, 'mango');

insert into dbo.tPurchase (id, quantity)
values (1, 15), (2, 10), (1, 5), (3, 25);

insert into dbo.tSale (id, quantity)
values (1, 5), (3, 10), (1, 5), (3, 5), (2, 5);

select
    p.id
    , p.product_name
    , pur.Quantity - sal.Quantity as Quantity
from dbo.tProduct p
    outer apply (
        select
            sum(tp.quantity) as Quantity
        from dbo.tPurchase tp
        where p.id = tp.id
    ) pur
    outer apply (
        select
            sum(tp.quantity) as Quantity
        from dbo.tSale tp
        where p.id = tp.id
    ) sal
```

Comment: I've changed my question can you check it for me